# Does the Quantifier apply to all?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, quantifiers

I have the following question:

> Let $f(x, y, z) = x^2y+z^3$, where $x, y, z \in \mathbb{Z}$. For each of the following determine its truth value.
> Justify your answers.
>
> (a)$\exists x, y, z: f(x, y, z) = 0$

My question: Does the $\exists$ affect the "$y$" and "$z$" as well? or is it only the $x$?

Also, if it does not affect the "$y$" and "$z$" variable, would those variables be some constant or something? Not too sure about that part.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: I have tried to improve the readability of your question by introducing [TeX](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/). It is possible that I unintentionally changed the meaning of your question. Please proofread the question to ensure this has not happened. For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $\exists$ affects all the variables. Writing $\exists x,y,z$ is short for $\exists x\exists y\exists z$.

If $\exists$ only affected one variable, then the formula wouldn't even be a statement exactly because there wouldn't be any quantification on the missing variables.

Comment: Perfect, Curious about the following: Would the following  ∀y, z∃x be ∀y, ∀z,∃x     && Same for this ∀y∃x, z  be ∀y∃x, ∃z  ?

Comment: Exactly!${{{}}}$

Comment: Perfect, Thank you for the clarification!

Comment: @amWhy, hmm is my answer wrong ? Not sure what you saying No to.

Comment: rawr I was following up on your comment/question, but missed which formulas you were equating with which. You are indeed correct, as is @GitGud.

Answer (score 1):

$\exists x,y,z$ is shorthand for $\exists x \exists y \exists z$ so your statement is true if you can find any triple $(x,y,z)$ that satisfies the equation.

Comment: Perfect, Curious about the following: Would the following  ∀y, z∃x be ∀y, ∀z,∃x     && Same for this ∀y∃x, z  be ∀y∃x, ∃z  ?

Comment: Yes, it would..